# Почему при наличии у родителя и его потомка положительного margin-top отступ у потомка не схлопывается, только если у родителя есть граница сверху?

Tags: css

Собственно в первом примере обозначаем бордер, во втором убираем. Смотрим что получилось:
Пример 1:
Здесь есть у родителя бордер:

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 24px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px #000000;
  border: solid 1px #ff3333;
  /*вот он*/
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #000000;
}
#child {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 240px;
  width: 320px;
  background-color: #0FF000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container page-container" id="parent" align="center">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

[[демо]](https://jsfiddle.net/t7fzugrk/)

Пример 2:
Здесь у родителя нет бордера

```css
 #parent {
   position: relative;
   margin-top: 24px;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px #000000;
   border: solid 0px #ff3333;
   /*вот его нет*/
   width: 600px;
   height: 400px;
   background-color: #000000;
 }
 #child {
   position: relative;
   margin-top: 100px;
   height: 240px;
   width: 320px;
   background-color: #0FF000;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container page-container" id="parent" align="center">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

[[демо 2]](https://jsfiddle.net/t7fzugrk/1/)

Внимание вопрос:
С чем связано такое поведение родителя и дочернего объекта?

---

**P.S. уже к админам проекта: Очень неудобно реализовано требование вставки кода из jsfiddle. Собирать воедино код из всех четырёх фреймов? Очень неудобно.**

Comment: немного отвлеченно - `Собирать воедино код из всех четырёх фреймов? Очень неудобно.` - у редатора есть кнопочка на верхней панели, если вы не заметили, вам на будущее:  `Фрагмент кода на Javascript/HTML/CSS` или горячая клавиша Ctrl+M .... там всё как у `jsfiddle` ;-)   ..... в результате можно прямо на сайте посмотреть выполненный код... как сейчас подправил я

Comment: Спасибо, буду иметь ввиду.

Comment: А какого поведения вы ожидаете, указывая **толщину** границы равной 0 прямо у себя в коде: `border: solid 0px #ff3333;`?

Comment: Если вы об отступе потомка от верхнего края родителя, то стоит почитать про "схлопывающиеся отступы": http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/blochnaya-verstka/skhlopyvayushchiesya-otstupy **P.S.** пожалуйста, в следующий раз точнее формулируйте суть вопроса, а не оставляйте один пример без комментария, что именно здесь не так.

Answer (score 3):

Все верно работает

1. margin работает внутри блока так как в блоке есть ограничения (border, padding, overflow:hidden), так же как и очистка потока
2. marginы схлопываются и двигают блок вниз как и положено

Поэтому используют clearfix и тп для того чтобы блоки были "нормального" размера, хотя суть в обратном - дать возможность засунуть блоки туда куда они засовываться не хотят.

... Написал все не технически, за технической частью в W3C.

Answer (score 2):

Верхние и нижние границы (margin) блоков иногда преобразуются (схлопываются) в одну границу, 
большую из двух соответствующих. Это поведение называется **"схлопывание границ" (margin collapsing)**.

```
|   A   |                                                              
|_______|                                      |   A   |               
          -                                    |_______|               
          - margin-bottom        станет                  - общая граница, равная большей
          -                   ----------->               - из двух, т.е. margin-bottom
---------                                       _______  -        
 _______  - margin-top                         |   B   |
|   B   |
```

Схлопывание границ происходит в трёх случаях, а так же когда эти случаи комбинируются.

**Смежные потомки одного родителя**

Границы смежных элементов одного родителя схлопываются (за исключением, когда последующий элемент очищается (clear) от предыдущих плавающих (float) элементов).

**Родитель и первый/последний потомок** (случай, рассматриваемый в вопросе)

Если нет рамки (border), внутренних отступов (padding), линейного содержимого, или очистки (clear) для разделения margin-top блока от margin-top его первого потомка или нет рамки, внутренних отступов линейного содержимого, height, min-height или max-height для разделения margin-bottom блока от margin-bottom его последнего потомка, тогда их границы схлопываются. Получившаяся таким образом граница будет расположена снаружи родительского элемента.

**Пустые блоки**

Если нет рамки, внутренних отступов, линейного содержимого, заданного свойства height или min-height, чтобы разделить margin-top блока от его margin-bottom, тогда верхние и нижние границы схлопываются.

Границы плавающих и абсолютно позиционируемых элементов никогда не схлопываются.

---

Ответ написан на основе статьи "[Mastering margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)".